# Одна кнопка на два листа

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, wpf-commands

Есть лист(Желаю прочитать) куда пользователь добавляет книги.И так же есть 2 кнопки.Первая которая переносит книгу в второй лист (Прочитонные книги).И Вторая которая удаляет элемент.И с помощью кнопки удаления пользователь может удалять книгу как из 1 так из 2 листа.Как сделать эту чертову кнопку удаления.

Вью:

```
<Window x:Class="BOOKLIST.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BOOKLIST"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="489.519" Width="826.987">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:BookVM/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <TextBox x:Name="BookName" Width="200" Height="30" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
            <Button Command="{Binding AddCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=BookName , Path=Text}" Height="30" Width="250" Content="Add To Whishlist" FontSize="20"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!-- Whishlist Zone -->
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5">
            <Label Width="200" Height="50" Content="Whishlist" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" FontSize="30" Margin="10"/>
            <ListBox x:Name="Whishlist" ItemsSource="{Binding WhishlistView}" Height="300" Width="300" />
        </StackPanel>

        <!-- Readed Zone -->
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5">
            <Label Width="200" Height="50" Content="Readed" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" FontSize="30" Margin="10"/>
            <ListBox x:Name="Readed" Height="300" Width="300"/>
        </StackPanel>
        
        <!-- Buttons (midle) -->
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Height="30" Margin="5" Content="Move to Readed" FontSize="20"/>
            <Button Command="{Binding RemoveCommand}" Height="25" Margin="10" Content="Remove" FontSize="17"/>
        </StackPanel>
        
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Это вью модель :

```
using Prism.Commands;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace BOOKLIST
{
    class BookVM
    {
        BookModel bookM;

        public DelegateCommand<string> AddCommand { get; private set; }
        public DelegateCommand RemoveCommand { get; private set; }
        public DelegateCommand MoveCommand { get; private set; }



        public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string> WhishlistView => bookM.Whishlist;
        public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string> ReadedView => bookM.Readed;

        public void Add(string value)
        {
            bookM.AddToWhishlist(value);
        }

        public void Move(int index)
        {
            
        }
        public void Remove(int index)
        {

        }

        public BookVM()
        {
            bookM = new BookModel();

            AddCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(Add);
        }
    }
}
```

модель

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace BOOKLIST
{
    class BookModel
    {
        private readonly ObservableCollection<string> _whishlist = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        public readonly ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string> Whishlist;

        private readonly ObservableCollection<string> _readed = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        public readonly ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string> Readed;

        public BookModel()
        {
            Whishlist = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string>(_whishlist);
            Readed = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string>(_readed);
        }


        public void AddToWhishlist(string value)
        {
            _whishlist.Add(value);
        }

        public void MoveToReaded(int index)
        {
            
        }
        public void Remove(int index , string listName)
        {
            if (listName == "Whishlist")
            {
                _whishlist.RemoveAt(index);
            }
            else if (listName == "Readed")
            {
                _readed.RemoveAt(index);
            }
        }
        public void MoveToReaded()
        {
            // For later
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1.Одна кнопка значит во View находится только одна кнопка.2.Из обоих ,одна кнопка удаления на 2 Listbox'a 3. Я изпользую MVVM патерн ...... не фреймворк. (Без негатива)

Comment: Что такое `DelegateCommand`? Такого класса не существует в чистом WPF. Покажите его код. Привязка к полям через `Binding` невозможна, должны быть свойства, например `public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string> Second { get; }`. Будет проще, если вы покажете код вьюмоделей целиком и XAML разметку.

Comment: Ну если вам нужно одной кнопкой удалить 2 элемента, тогда просто надо прибиндить к свойствам в вьюмодель `SelectedItem` каждого листбокса, тогда во вьюмодели будете наверняка знать, какой элемент выделен и просто `_first.Remove(FirstSelectedItem)`. Еще не видно, где вы `RemoveCommand` создаете.

Comment: _Я изпользую MVVM патерн ...... не фреймворк_ А это тогда что? `using Prism.Commands;` - это MVVM фреймворк Prism.

Comment: Нет.щяс попробую обьяснить есть два ListBox и там кнопка которая будет перемещять один элемент из одного листа в другой.И допустим мне надо удолить один элемент из первого листа.Но что бы во втором все осталось как было или наоборот.И тоесть что бы функция `Remove` работала как бы и так `_first.RemoveAt(index);` и так `_second.RemoveAt(index)` но удаляла именно из того Listbox'a на которой этот элемент выбран

Comment: про фреймворк забыл простите моя вина.

Comment: Почему не сделать по-человечески тогда? 2 кнопки между двумя листбоксами, одна перемещает элементы влево, вторая вправо. Пользователю точно так понятнее не будет? Ведь с точки зрения пользователя он не удаляет и не добавляет ничего, он именно перемещает. Отсюда и UX логика вырастает, и интерфейс верстается. Опять же, привяжите `SelectedItem`ы, проще будет реализовать это все. Если вам упортно надо знать, что за листбокс выбран, пробуйте привязать `IsFocused`, но с фокусами в WPF не все так просто, придется попотеть, настроить везде `Focusable` и т.д.

Comment: Там 2 кнопки.Для перемещения и для удаления мне надо что бы кнопка для удаления могла удалять и из 1 листа и из 2 листа.Делаю я это для того что бы не было 2 кнопки удаления

Comment: Но я бы вообще на базе одной коллекции с фильтрами `ICollectionView` это делал, и коллекцию не строк, а классов со строкой и bool IsSelected внутри. К сожалению, я не знаком с Prism, поэтому примерами не помогу. Может кто другой поможет.

Comment: Тогда я вообще ничего не понял, какую задачу вы решаете? Можете не с кнопками и листами, а словами рассказать? Желаемое поведение какое, но не в смысле "кнрпка должна", а в смысле "пользователь должен иметь возможность", и не "удалять/добавлять", а какую там задачу хочет решить пользователь? Вы пишете про удаление, а добавление как происходит?

Comment: Есть лист(Желаю прочитать) куда пользователь добавляет книги.И так же есть 2 кнопки.Первая которая переносит книгу в второй лист (Прочитонные книги).И Вторая которая удаляет элемент.И с помощью кнопки удаления пользователь может удалять книгу как из 1 так из 2 листа

Comment: Про `ICollectionView` с фильтрами - самая удачная идея. У вас будет всего одна коллекция, которая содержит все добавленные элементы и 2 листбокса, один показывает выбранные, второй все остальные. Получится так, что при удалении выбранного элемента он будет удален из одной коллекции. Единственный минус, все-таки придется повозиться с `Focused`, чтобы на уровне вьюмодели знать, какой из листбоксов сейчас в фокусе. Быть может напишу пример, но позже, возможно завтра, без Prosm, сейчас нет возможности. А может, кто-то другой ответит. Сейчас вопрос выглядит более-менее понятно.